# Is there a simple way to make a .png photo take less disk space and load faster?

Tags: image, png

I have an image that is pretty large in size, and I am trying to figure out how to reduce its size. Googling didn't make things clear. I thought just simply resaving it in some clever way would make the image take way less disk space.  Is there a simple way to get that done?

Comment: You want it to be lossless?  You may have a problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29

Comment: @ConradShultz it is ok to lose some quality in the photo :) I don't mind that.

Comment: In that case, sjums has your answer.

Comment: You stated the answer in your question: *"reduce its size"* There's no magic button.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com). It exactly does re-saving with better compression parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with png, but jpeg for example can be compressed, which of course changes the quality.

Else you have the option to make the image's dimensions smaller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize the image using command line tools, make sure [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is installed, then use the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command:

```
$ convert example.png -scale 640x example-smaller.png
$ ls -l example*.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  1015303 Jan 14 16:12 example.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel   305456 Jan 31 00:26 example-smaller.png
$ file example*.png
example.png:         PNG image, 1548 x 882, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
example-smaller.png: PNG image, 640 x 365, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
$
```

And as sjums said, converting to jpeg (which is lossy) may also be your answer:

```
$ convert example.png example.jpg
$ ls -l example.*
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  1015303 Jan 14 16:12 example.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel   407071 Jan 31 00:30 example.jpg
$
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .png format, you can save in 8 bit, 24 bit, and 32 bit colour depths.  Obviously 8 and 24 bit have MUCH smaller file sizes.  I am not sure how to do this programmatically, but I use Adobe Fireworks for this task all the time with fantastic results.  One detriment to sticking with the reduced colour depth .png formats is the inability to keep a transparent background, but that's the price ou pay for reducing data size :(

P.S. I use Fireworks CS4, I'm sure the newer versions do an even better job of compression.